# Leanback seekbar focuse

Tags: android-tv

I override the xml file of "lb_playback_fragment" to make some changes and my playerback fragment is inherited from VideoSupportFragment().

For some of my videos I would like to disable rewind so is there any way to change leanback seekbar focusable value with code (not inside the xml file)?